# Jetty 8 centralize logging with slf4j

Tags: logging, jetty, slf4j, logback

i am currently try to configure centralized logging for jetty 8 with slf4j. I found the following [tutorial][1] but it seems not to work with jetty 8. Does someone knows how to do this with jetty 8?

Solution:

jetty-webapp-logging.xml must have the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- Enable Centralized Logging in the Jetty Server                  -->
<!-- =============================================================== -->

<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <Ref id="DeploymentManager">
    <Call name="addLifeCycleBinding">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.logging.CentralizedWebAppLoggingBinding">
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
  </Ref>
</Configure>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the the tutorial, [Centralized Logging with Logback](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/example-logging-logback-centralized.html), was created for Jetty 9, all of the features it is using is available as well on Jetty 8.1.10.

Some advice:

1. Use the [correct version of the jetty-webapp-logging](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.mortbay.jetty%7Cjetty-webapp-logging%7C8.1.10.v20130312%7Cjar) jar for Jetty 8.1.10.
2. Use the [correct version of the  DOCTYPE](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/jetty.xml_syntax#Basic_Example) when working with the XML files.
3. The command lines using `start.jar` are the same.
4. The `start.ini` changes are the same.

Finally, various logging examples can be found at

https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-and-logback-example

(tip: build the maven projects then look in the various `${module}/target/jetty-distro/` for the configured distribution that these maven builds produce)